# Can not find jsonapi parser 0.1.1

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

When I run rails server, 'Could not find jsonapi-parser-0.1.1.beta2' error shows up.

```
~/ruby_on_rails/test/sampleapp$ rails s
Could not find jsonapi-parser-0.1.1.beta2 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
~/ruby_on_rails/test/sampleapp$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Could not find jsonapi-0.1.1.beta4 in any of the sources
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
bundle update jsonapi
```

should fix it

Answer (score 1):

jsonapi beta4 is not available. only beta5, beta 1,beta2 are available. you could find this [here](https://rubygems.org/gems/jsonapi/versions/0.1.1.beta5)

Add this line in your gemfile if not  and then run bundle install.

`gem 'jsonapi-parser', '~> 0.1.1.beta2'
 gem 'jsonapi', '~> 0.1.1.beta5'`

This might be due to the method which requires jsonparser which is not included in your rails app.