# Rails 5 could not find jsonapi-parser-0.1.1.beta2 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, active-model-serializers, json-api

After installing the active_model_serializer gem, I try to generate the serializers but it fails. See screenshot below

[image]

Comment: what happens when you run bundle install?

Comment: bundle install completes without any new installation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can not find jsonapi parser 0.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39887721/can-not-find-jsonapi-parser-0-1-1)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem solved after switching to the default gemset.

Answer (score 2):

That fix works for me:

`bundle update jsonapi`